# Use a Windows XP box to proxy a VPN connection for a LAN

Tags: windows-xp, osx-lion, vpn, proxy

I work on a Mac machin and need to connect to the VPN of my work but the connection from the Mac is a pain. The connections drops in a short period, don't resolve host names, etc.

How can I connect my Windows box to the VPN and share the connection to my Mac?

Thanks